# adding slash "/" to URL

Tags: php, url, yii

I have the following text

```
Car/red
```

i want it to be sent withing the url 
ex:

```
http://ii/search/index/search/Car%2Fred/page/2
```

but doing  so gives the "Search" query string only the "car" and ignore the "red" part
how can we encode the slash so in can be sent within the URL ?

Comment: What you show should work. What server are you using and what does your rewrite method look like?

Comment: i am running php on fedora and the $_GET["string"] gets only the first part

Comment: You are rewriting the URL. What do the rules look like?

Comment: i just try echo $_GET["search"] and i get car ...

Comment: The URL you show above does not contain a "search" parameter, does it? So some rewriting is taking place somewhere. This is impossible to answer without getting some more relevant information.

Comment: what do you get if you var dump the entire $_GET variable?

Comment: array(3) { ["search"]=> string(3) "car" ["a"]=> string(4) "page" [2]=> string(0) "" }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using urlFormat '**path**' you're not able to submit slashes in parameters, because Yii can't distinguish between them. See [Qiang's comment](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/1700-urlmanager-with-path-format-and-having-encoded-slashes-as-parameter/page__view__findpost__p__9682).

As a workaround set:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  'appendParams'=>false,
),
```

Your URL should look like this then:

http://ii/search/index?search=Car/red&page=2

You may also add rewrite rules for having the page param in a nicer way in the URL.